# Android system link failing - function on implemented

Tags: android

I'm trying to create a symbolic link inside my android sdcard using this line of code into android terminal emulator:

```
ln -sv /storage/sdcard0/WhatsApp/ProfilePictures storage/sdcard0/WhatsApp/Media/WhatsAppProfilePhotos
```

but i'm getting this error:

```
Function not implemented
```

any idea what am i doing wrong and how can i solve this?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that `ProfilePictures` and `WhatsAppProfilePhotos` are folders.

Then if you want to create a symlink between folders you need to add the trailing slash, like this:

```
ln -sv /storage/sdcard0/WhatsApp/ProfilePictures/ storage/sdcard0/WhatsApp/Media/WhatsAppProfilePhotos
```

EDIT:
It seems like android's shell doesn't support it:

```
root@generic_x86_64:/ # ln
usage:  ln [-fhinsv] file1 file2
        ln [-fhinsv] file ... directory
```

Comment: I managed to solve this using an app called foldersync...with a bit of work seams like it does allow you to do something similar to what i'm after.